# react-router-dom@6 does not browse and does not display pages

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

I started a new project and decided to use react-router-dom@6 to navigate between my pages.
I did the installation and configuration, but the navigation is not working and I could not find the problem.
I need that when accessing "/" the "Home" page is displayed and that when accessing "/profile" the Profile page is displayed.
Name at the moment localhost:3000 only displays a blank page like "/home" and "/profile''.
I didn't identify the problem.

**Index.js**

```
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-filename-extension */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './i18n';
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.js**

```
/* eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope */
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-filename-extension */
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Routes from './routes';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes />
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**routes.js**

```
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
/* eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope */
/* eslint-disable react/jsx-filename-extension */
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
import React from 'react';
import {
  Routes,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from './pages/home';
import Profile from './pages/profile';

function MainRoutes() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default MainRoutes;
```

**Home.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import React from 'react';

const { t } = useTranslation();

function Home() {
  return (
    <h1>
      {t('home.title')}
      ;
    </h1>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

**Profile.jsx**

```
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import React from 'react';

const { t } = useTranslation();

function Profile() {
  return (
    <h1>
      {t('home.title')}
      ;
    </h1>
  );
}

export default Profile;
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "bruno-profile",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "i18next": "^21.6.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-i18next": "^11.15.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out this guide for a correct react-i18next usage: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb

Comment: I don't see any issue with any of your routing code. Only thing that sticks out is the invalid React hook usage. Certainly you can see console errors/warnings informing of such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call useTranslation() hook inside the react component body, you have to change it in both fies Home.jsx and Profile.jsx.

```
function Home() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  return <h1>{t("home.title")};</h1>;
}
```